# Conditionally including JS based on whether ACF field is set

Tags: filters, pages, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to include a javascript file in the head of a WordPress page based on whether or not a particular field nested inside a flexible content field nested inside a repeater is set or not.

I can't seem to find anything in the ACF documentation that suggests this kind of functionality is provided. (Someone vaguely mentioned there might be a filter I could use, but I can't seem to find it.) Would I have to write something to query the field outside the loop, or is there a more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Loop isn't available yet in `wp_enqueue_scripts`, so is_single() etc pp aren't going to work.
However, the queried object has already been determined, so you could use something like

```
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", function() {
    $qo = get_queried_object();
    if(get_class($qo) == "WP_Post") {
        if($val = get_field("my-field", $qo->ID)) {
            wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: side note, the `$post` object is set before any template is lodaded and also the query object. This code, while might work, is pointlessly long

Comment: That is correct, but `$post` will also be set (to the first post in the loop) if you're looking at an archive. `get_queried_object()` is more specific.

Comment: everything is set, you can just call `is_single()`. No loop is initialized but the only thing a loop does is inceremt the counter of the loop and set all relevant global for the context of the next post.

Comment: That's true, I was testing with pages for which is_single() is always false and got confused.